# Dispose a AutoResetEvent after signaling it

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispose, idisposable, autoresetevent

Let's suppose we have a class **MyQueue** defined as below:

```
public class MyQueue
{
    private bool _stop;
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _onQueued = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<int> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
    
    public MyQueue()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(ManageQueue)
        {
            IsBackground = true
        };
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void EnqueueInt(int num)
    {
         _queue.Enqueue(num);
         _onQueued.Set();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
       _stop = true;
       _onQueued.Set();
    }

    private void ManageQueue()
    {
        while (!_stop)
        {
            onQueued.WaitOne();
            int tempNum;

            while(!_stop && _queue.TryDequeue(out tempNum))
            {
                 // Do something with the int
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So pratically we have a method `EnqueueInt` used to queue item inside the data structure and a `thread` that cyclically checks if the queue has item to be processed. The signal `_onQueued` is used to signal the thread when a new item is inserted or a close operation has been started. My question is: MyQueue has a disposable object (of type **AutoResetEvent**) and must be disposed when the queue is no longer needed, but, what's the best way to dispose it?
Calling `Dispose` after a `Close()` operation could be very dangerous because of the `Set()` invocation in it and I've no garantee that the Thread has terminated its cycle.

Comment: Join the thread, and then dispose the event.

Comment: Do you need to delete the queue?  Can you not just ignore it?  If queues are continually being created and then, later, are no longer required for their original purpose, can you not just store them in a pool container for re-use instead of creating new ones all tbe time?

Answer (score 0):

Instead or re-inventing the wheel, you can use [System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-6.0)

Also, if you want to manage the lifetime of your queue, I would use a service, so when the service (queue service) is disposed, then you can dispose of it; here is the Microsoft guide on how to create a queue service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/queue-service